# django same localhost not responding in another browser or second instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, localhost

my new created django project working fine with this information

```
Django version 2.1.7, using settings 'django_server_api.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

running fine

then i opened in one browser is loaded quickly working quickly.

but if i open same local host in another browser it is taking more than 5 minutes, i dont know what is the issues? may be django is like this? or do i need to change any config in the setting,py file ?

Comment: basically it depend's upon your system RAM

Comment: i can run multiple Angualr js application in diiferent browser , only issues is with django, in my 8gb ram

Comment: i think your running in debuging mode...?

Comment: yes right , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers (Firefox) has a problem browsing to localhost on some Windows machines.

You can solve it by switching off ipv6, which isn't really recommended.

Using 127.0.0.1 directly is another way round the problem.

Note : If there are heavy media is can also slow downs django

Comment: i tried windows and ubuntu both have same and exact issues.no logs only it showng waiting for local host...,